# Magento collection iterator - cannot get additional attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I can't get additional attribute 'name' from product collection when I'm using resource iterator.

My product collection:

```
        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $subCategories))->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', '4')
        ->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Iterator:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), array(array($this, 'generateXml')));
```

generateXml function:

```
public function generateXml($args){
    var_dump($args['row']);
...

array(11) {
  ["entity_id"]=>
  string(5) "49335"
  ["entity_type_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["attribute_set_id"]=>
  string(2) "18"
  ["type_id"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["sku"]=>
  NULL
  ["has_options"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["required_options"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2014-05-28 19:18:49"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2014-05-28 19:20:21"
  ["category_id"]=>
  string(3) "236"
  ["visibility"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead:

```
(...)
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name')
(...)
```

should be:

```
(...)
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'),'inner')
(...)
```

Comment: Finally I found it! All examples I've found so far suggest addAttributeToSelect('name') or addAttributeToSelect(array('name')) which didn't work at all. Adding a join types solved this for me. One should probably be careful not to add too many joins this way or performance may take a serious hit :-)

Comment: Quick side note: the second parameter is $jointype, and valid values seem to be false, "inner" or "left".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking to accomplish.  However, below may help guide you a little.  Even though, I'm not to familiar with the resource_interator this may help

```
<?php
// $this-> may not work depending upon block type. However this helper is what allows you to grab other necessary values     
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');  
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    // ->addCategoryFilter($category) If you have the category object you can filter by this
    // I'm just using the below example to grab these three attribute values. 
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'product_url', 'small_image'))
    ->load();
?>

            <!-- Display Each product's detailed info  Granted this is not in an xml format.  Which you can alter to your needs,  but this should be a good base point I don't believe the resource  -->
        <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
            <li>
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($product->getName(), null, true); ?>

            <!-- Below is where the helper is needed for product name.  -->
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($product, $product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h3>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for help. I would avoid use this solution because in this case I'm working with large collection.